# Typescript HTML basic button with out Angular or React possible?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am new to typescript and I was wondering why my .ts code is not working with my HTML code (because my HTML does run, but the buttons don't work).
I am trying to do this **without angular and without react**
I have this code and have transpiled the .ts to .js, but nothing I've seen from examples is working to make the code run.

running on Intellij

Right now I have the code as simple as possible: **the button is supposed to just run an alert.**

there are 2 buttons where I try to test my code in the HTML File
:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">
```

and

```
<button onclick="loginTs.validateInput()">Forgot Password?</button>
```

> this is my HTML code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<header>
    <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <div id="tabs">

        <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="loginTabFun()">Log in</p>
        <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()">Register</p>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cont">

        <div id="login" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>

            <input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">

            <button onclick="loginTs.validateInput()">Forgot Password?</button>
        </div>


        <div id="register" class="comm">
            <h3>Register</h3>

            <input id="re" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="rp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input id="rrp" type="password" placeholder="Re write Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="register()" value="Submit"/>

        </div >


        <div id="forgot" class="comm">
            <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="fe" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="forgot()" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> this is my .ts code:

```
    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {                                                 
        this.username=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("email")).value;                      
        this.password=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("password")).value;                   
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
        let submitBtn= document.getElementById("enter")                                                
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>{ return this.validateInput();});               
    }                                                                                                  
                                                                                                       
    validateInput(){                                                                                   
             alert("wrong user or password but good job erin")                                         
    }                                                                                                  
let loginTs = new LoginTs("billy", "bronco");
```

Comment: I assume you're referring to this line: `<button onclick="loginTs.validateInput()">`  If you want to access a function in another file, you'll need to `import` or `require` it first.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I did in the HTML with **<script src="LoginTs.js"></script> ** I've had a .js project and it worked this way, is there extra importing I have to do, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I haven't worked without modules in a long time.  Your js file still needs to `export` something (like a global) or attach something to the `window` if you want to access functions from it.